# How to save a JSON file to Jupyter dir using JQuery inside Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jquery, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to save a JSON file in the Jupyter directory using a jquery code that is written in the main.min.js(jupyter js file) and calling it on a notebook cell via a html button?.

Here is my code that is added on main.min.js(jupyter js file)

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "../static/custom/save_nodetypes.html", 
  data: nodeTypes, //json data
  method: 'post',
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
  },
  success: function(data){
    alert('success');
  }
 });
```

This gives me an error that is:

```
jquery.min.js:6 POST http://localhost:8888/static/custom/save_nodetypes.html 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```